# Convert string to variable name in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert a string to a variable name in TypeScript. I am trying to use the string as an *src attribute in an *img* tag. I am using React.

An abbreviated version of what I am trying to do:

```
import example from './example.png';

function Foo () {
   const str = 'example';

   return (
      <img src={CONTENTS_OF_str_AS_A_VARIABLE} />
   );
};

export default Foo;
```

Note that in my actual code I am building the contents of `str` dynamically, so I can't just type `'example'` in the *src* attribute of the *img*.

I looked online and found I can use `window` to convert the string to a variable, but when I try that I get the following error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'. ts(7015)`. My updated code looks something like this:

```
import example from './example.png';

function Foo () {
   const str = 'example';

   return (
      <img src={window[str]} />
   );
};

export default Foo;
```

Everything I find online addresses how to use window, but not how to type it. How can I fix this so my code works correctly?

Comment: In short, don't. Try to rework your design instead.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. However, if you want to play around with type casting, you can try with ```window[str as keyof typeof window]```. But it is not recommended :)